# IE and Edge does not respect the text-transform

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have the following situation I can't explain but the Microsoft browser's bug...

I have a symbolic font, and use different letters to display symbols. By example, the "z" letter is to display the "decrease font size" symbol, and the "Z" for the "increase font size" one...

However the Microsoft browsers lowercases my letters, and I have the same "z" in Edge and IE, however a correct behavior in normal browsers.

[image]

**The bug can be observed [here](https://www.eurovia.pl/aktualnosci/projekty-badawcze) (in IE or Edge).**

What can I do to fix it?

PS.

I tried to reproduce this in this snipped, but actually is working as fixed...
However in the link bellow the bug is reproduced...

```css
body {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

span.symbol.a::before {
  content: " <A-xample of UPPERCASE text> ";
}
span.symbol.b::before {
  content: " <B-xample of UPPERCASE text> ";
}

.symbol::before {
  text-transform: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  this is a text div
  <span class="symbol a"></span>
  <span class="symbol b"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant CSS in a code snippet and not in a image. Also IE and Edge are "normal" browsers

Comment: You should add the relevant code in a snippet because if the website goes offline or the code changes the question wouldn't make sense without it. Also we don't dig trough external source codes

Comment: We don't need a working example just the code snippet. I mean if it was working it wasn't a question. And yes they are normal browsers just bad browsers. Hopefully Edge will change when they start using chromium

Comment: @SuperDJ, I added the snippet, but now you will say there's no problem, however there is a problem on the working site...

Comment: so, you will close the question because I can't reproduce it in a snippet, if I understood well...?

Answer (score 0):

The only (and ugly) solution I found for this issue, is to use Unicode codes instead of the letters. It means, even if the *buggy Microsoft browsers* lowsercases the symbols, they can't lowsercase a UPPERCASE code letter.

By eg. instead of use `content: "Z"` I would use `content: "\005A"` and instead of `content: "z"` => `content: "\007A"`
In that case, even the "bad" Microsoft browsers (Edge and IE) displays the correct cased char.

Comment: I try to test the above sample code with IE and Edge but not able to produce the issue. However, you had posted the answer for your question. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT as said in the OP, the sample does not reproduce the problem, because maybe there some things I missed when trying to reproduce the problem in a sample. I can't reproduce it in the sample. BUT the problem DOES EXIST in the link I posted. IT DOES EXIST, and it exists only on EGDE AND IE. Actually it is fixed with the unicode code as the solution I posted, but easy reproductible if you put the letter instead of the code using F12 tools. Thanks for the conprehension.

Comment: the solution I posted is not a genuine fix, but a workaround, so the browsers have some bugs needed to be fixed to correspond to the normal browsers like Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I posed the sample, because admins like @SuperDJ asked me to put a sample. But the sample unfortunately does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can try to modify your original post and try to provide a detailed step by step information to produce the issue. We will again try to produce the issue and try to check for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: as I already wrote, the existing live example on the site the link I posted reproduces the problem... as I wrote, in the live site, you replace (F12 tools/CSS Styles) the existing ('fixed') unicode code "\005A" by the "Z" letter, and here is your problem reproduction.

Comment: instead of declared in CSS "Z" it will take de facto the little "z", and that is only on the Edge and IE browsers...

Comment: I try to follow your steps as you had mentioned in comment. Still Issue is not producible. Here is the testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/rswSmJ4d/106.png You can inform me, If I miss any point here. I will try to correct my self.